# Difference between callUDF and udf.register in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a udf as part of an import and I am using it in my spark code

```
    spark.sql("""DROP TEMPORARY FUNCTION IF EXISTS hash""")
    val name = "hash"
    spark.sql(s"create temporary function $name as '${classOf[GenericHash].getName}'")
    val hash = callUDF(name, _: Column)
```

It works fine, but I am told to register the UDF with udf.register. What does this operator _: do? When I try to write it like this

```
val hash = spark.sqlContext.udf.register(name, classOf[GenericHash].getName)
```

I get an error message

```
error]  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Char is not supported (ScalaReflection.scala:780)
[error] org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:780)
[error] org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:715)
[error] org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:824)
```

Is there anyway to write it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UDFRegistration.register` comes in variants that take:

- [`UserDefinedFunction`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a4c03f7d084f1d2aa48673b99f3b9496893ce8d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L103-L107)
- [`UserDefinedAggregateFunction`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a4c03f7d084f1d2aa48673b99f3b9496893ce8d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L76-L80)
- [`UDF0`, `UDF1`, ..., `UDF22`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a4c03f7d084f1d2aa48673b99f3b9496893ce8d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L140-L162), for example  [for binary functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration@register(name:String,f:org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2[_,_,_],returnType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType):Unit):

  ```
  def register(name: String, f: UDF2[_, _, _], returnType: DataType): Unit
  ```
- [Scala `Function0`, `Function1`, ..., `Function22`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a4c03f7d084f1d2aa48673b99f3b9496893ce8d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L113-L138) for example  for binary functions

  ```
  def register[RT, A1, A2](name: String, func: (A1, A2) ⇒ RT)(implicit arg0: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.TypeTag[RT], arg1: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.TypeTag[A1], arg2: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.TypeTag[A2]): UserDefinedFunction
  ```

There is no variant which takes a class name. Your code doesn't fail compilation only because `String` in `Scala` is `(Int) => Char` therefore matches

```scala
def register[RT, A1](name: String, func: (A1) ⇒ RT)(implicit arg0: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.TypeTag[RT], arg1: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.TypeTag[A1]): UserDefinedFunction
```

But that's of course not what you mean.